# Изменение размера картинки при widht<768 при помощи bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу чтобы картинка занимала 50% или 70% экрана при ширине меньшей, чем 768 пкс. Как это сделать?

Я знаю что нужно использовать @media, но я не очень в этом разбираюсь.

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
   width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  img {
     display: table;
     margin: 0 auto;
     width: 50%;
  }
}
```

Comment: если размера экрана, то `width: 50vw`.

Comment: картинка получилась прижатой к левому краю. как исправить?

Comment: исправил в своём ответе